# Cross Origin Request Error d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm a novice d3 programmer, and I'm using a JSON file and a function called arcDiagram to build my visualization. However, whenever I try the following method:  *d3.json("assets/data/tang_seg1.json", arcDiagram);*

I get a cross origin request error. Looked online but I'm still stumped; any help would be appreciated :)

Edit: I am running this using my own server, so localhost:8000.

Comment: Are you running this app using a web server, or by file url (i.e. by double-clicking your HTML file)?

Comment: Change your method to sample like this: `d3.json("path/to/file.json", function(error, json) {
  if (error) return console.warn(error);
 arcDiagram=json;
});`   you got error because of `arcDiagram`.

Comment: On the [D3 documentation page](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki) there are instructions on how to use it.